# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load aacdecoder from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: java, android, android-library

I'm trying to play a aac in my app using aacdecoder lib

So the problem is that when I use this code:

```
AACPlayer aacPlayer = new AACPlayer();
aacPlayer.playAsync( "http://cast.direcnode.com:11320/stream" );
```

My app crash

I have put all the files in my libs folder:

```
>libs
    >armeabi
        >libaacdecoder.so
    >armeabi-v7a
        >libaacdecoder.so
    >mips
        >libaacdecoder.so
    >x86
        >libaacdecoder.so
    >aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar
```

And I have add the jar file to the build.gradle

```
compile files('libs/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar')
```

But when I run the code It says this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load aacdecoder from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ger.radio-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ger.radio-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

I've tried everything, please help me

Thanks in advanced